# Building a REST API in Laravel

Tags: php, rest, unit-testing, laravel-5

I'm going from no-framework development to my first contact with Laravel (using version 5.1) and I'm a bit overwhelmed with the amount of stuffs to handle (migrations, seeds, hateoas, transformers, unit testing, error handling, etc).

I'd like to get some help at the return of the `show method` portion of it (following REST concepts). I have the following database structure:

> companies -> users -> tickets -> interactions -> attachments

[image]

Now, when listing a specific ticket (like `GET /customers/5/tickets/3`), the screen needs to show all interactions for that ticket, along with all information in the ticket table (sort of like a page header) and the name of each user that created the specific interaction.

Thinking in terms of relationship, should I return all that data from the single call or should the information from the tickets table, for instance, be persisted in the front-end (from the `index method` call)? Even if I should persist the ticket information (header of the page), I am still left with `interaction join users` + N attachments for each interaction. What are the options to approach this?

I decided to open this thread because I was trying to Unit Test this call and I couldn't decide whether I should seed the database to have all the information necessary for it to work.

### Edit

To better clarify my request, I'm not in doubt on how to handle the database communication, I already have my models set extending Eloquent class and I defined the hasMany, belongsTo, etc data.

```
namespace App\Models;

class Company extends Model {

    /**
     * Get the users from the company.
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function users() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\User');
    }
}
```

To not make the post bigger than it needs to be, I'll settle with just providing the Company model. I hope you all get the concept that I have **Company**, **User**, **Ticket**, **Interaction** and **Attachment** models all set and ready to use.

### Edit 2

The question is around the practice in handling it. Should the  `GET /customers/5/tickets/3` return the **ticket** record, all **interactions** for it, the **user** for each interaction, all the **attachments** for each interactions? Isn't that over responsibility for a single endpoint? Like I mentioned above, I think I can demand from the front-end to persist the ticket information from when the front-end listed all tickets, that takes out the burden of the **ticket** record, but it's still a TicketController and there are still a lot of data to be loaded. I'm seeking for advice on handling this much information because I never did it before and I would like to minimize the amount of things I'll regret for doing.

Comment: Read about Eloquent ORM on laravel.com/docs/5.1. You need to create Models for each of these, create relationships between them and then use the relationships to query data (get or post). Forget about the other stuff till then.

Comment: I already have all that that you just mentioned.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. You will need to have a controller. That controller will have function, one of which will be your json api call entry point. That function will return a json blob which in laravel is done by returning a type of response object. Inside that function is some code to pull the data from the data models. The function is accessed by a route. Which bit do you need help with?

Comment: @delatbabel I edited again.

Comment: Ok rereading your edit, I would say that it's perfectly ok to return all of the interactions that way. Modern browsers have useful local storage and you should use that where you can to prevent frequent api calls. However if the number of interactions is likely to be large then put them into a different controller call with pagination

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu In more general advice, for learning a powerful but complex and abstract (and sometimes a little unpolished) framework like Laravel, I find it helpful to slow down, focus on one specific thing, learn the *right* way to do it, and then move onto the next challenge. That will serve you a lot better than trying to figure out everything at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should return all the information your API consumers will need to display one ticket entry. I've worked on projects where there were query parameters to tell the server which related models to include, and others where subsequent AJAX calls were needed to get the associated data, but I think that's needlessly complex unless the interaction data is huge or very rarely needed.

I would recommend creating view partials for each model, so that you have flexibility in case one large view doesn't work out.

Solving the N+1 query problem you mentioned is trivial though. Here is a perfect situation for [eager loading](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

Try something like this: `$tickets = Tickets::with('interactions','user')->get()`

That will load all associated data in one query.